# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm having `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport` exception while running the project. I'm using **elasticsearch-7.3.1**.

**Gradle File Dependencies:**

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch',version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport',version: '7.3.1'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-client', version: '7.3.1'
```

**Client Class:**

```
    @Configuration
    public class Config{
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host:localhost}")
    public String host;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.port:9300}")
    public int port;
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    @Bean
    public Client client(){

        TransportClient client = null;
        try{

             client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));



        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/techno/homes/search/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/http/AbstractHttpServerTransport
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:594)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.get(HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.java:42)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.healthIndicatorRegistry(HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4291cf05.CGLIB$healthIndicatorRegistry$2()
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4291cf05$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$24eb705c.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4291cf05.healthIndicatorRegistry()
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>       ... 94 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/techno/homes/search/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/http/AbstractHttpServerTransport
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1350)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1209)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
>       ... 127 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/http/AbstractHttpServerTransport
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>       ... 144 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/http/AbstractHttpServerTransport
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
>       at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.getSettings(Netty4Plugin.java:52)
>       at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$getPluginSettings$0(PluginsService.java:87)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>       at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>       at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getPluginSettings(PluginsService.java:87)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:145)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.(TransportClient.java:283)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:116)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:106)
>       at com.techno.homes.search.Config.client(Config.java:34)
>       at com.techno.homes.search.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee00138e.CGLIB$client$0()
>       at com.techno.homes.search.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee00138e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c26abbc4.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>       at com.techno.homes.search.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee00138e.client()
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>       ... 145 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 
>   I'm working over this for hours but unable to identify the issue. Please help me figure this out

Answer (score 4):

If someone is using version 5.4.0 and is getting this error, just add custom dependency for netty4 solved the issue for me. Before that it was downloading 7.2.0 depency of netty4.

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '5.4.0'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '5.4.0'
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-client', version: '5.4.0'
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful for folks on older versions of the elasticsearch package. As per @p-j-meisch's answer this answer also fixes the error by pulling in the main elasticsearch package which includes the AbstractHttpServerTransport.

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractHttpServerTransport` lives in the server package that is contained in the *org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch* library, you are only inlcuding the client library.

I would recommend to change your code to use the Rest client as the `TransportClient` is deprecated in the 7 versions of Elasticsearch and will be removed in version 8. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html)